# Rcompanion: Robust ANOVA: Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : Results do not have equal lengths

Tags: r, anova

I want to calculate robust ANOVA as explained on https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/d_08a.html . I am getting the error "Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : Results do not have equal lengths".

1. What does the error mean?
2. What is causing it?

I am using the `groupwiseHuber` function of rcompanion. R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

```
Sum = groupwiseHuber(data = y2,
                     group = c("antifungal", "dose"),
                     var = "avg_rad",
                     conf.level=0.95,
                     conf.type="wald")

Sum
```

My data.frame looks like this:

```
structure(list(y = c(9.91e+08, 8.17e+08, 461200000, 15330000, 
175100000, 50320000, 13590000, 22970000, 2778000, 3453000, 12890000, 
375900000, 44590000, 1.611e+09, 1e+09, 889900000, 373200000, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5010000, 6549000, 23160000, 32520000, 7707000, 
556900000, 634600000, 820900000, 391400000, 498300000, 147900000, 
646900000, 22060000, 1e+07, 306800000, 319400000, 41290000, 94100000, 
127200000, 117200000, 618300000, 570700000, 617100000, 284900000, 
449600000, 3866000, 6918000, 4177000, 14870000, 29380000, 2815000, 
1619000, 3126000, 1710000, 2191000), x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("untreated", "VRZ", "AMB"
), class = "factor"), dose = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("0", "5", "20"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-57L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NA`'s in your dependent variable are causing the error.

You can remove them with

```
y2 = subset(y2, !is.na(y))
```

It appears that the `groupwiseHuber()` function doesn't handle any `NA` values. This has to do with the output produced by `DescTools::HuberM` when there is an `NA` value and when a confidence interval is requested.  I'm seeing if the function can be improved in this respect, but the simple solution is to simply remove `NA` values.

Comment: Note that the function documentation says, "*It is recommended to remove NA values before using this function. At the time of writing, NA values will cause the function to fail.*"

Comment: Thanks @sal, your solution worked. I should have checked for NAs straight away. I had a similar problem with a different function recently.

Comment: One more question, though: what does the error message "results do not have equal length" really mean? I just would like to understand better.

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain.  I think it has to with the fact, that, if there are NA's and a confidence interval is asked for, `DescTools::HuberM` returns a single value, but if there are no NA's and a confidence interval is asked for, it returns a small data frame.  `rcompanion::groupwiseHuber()` uses the *plyr* package to create the groups, and then *DescTools* to get the Huber estimators.  So, it's basically a case of the packages not producing the results that the other packages are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I get the idea.